# Can't start a campaign using foursquare api

Tags: foursquare

I have a venue which is currently running 1 active campaign, 1 scheduled campaign, and 1 pending campaign. If I start the pending campaign using the api it throws an error "the following venues already have 2 active specials"

Comment: Can you provide more details? i.e. the full request URL (minus the oauth token) and response you're receiving from the API?

Comment: I think there's a bug that affects a certain number of venues with this problem -- I've asked the relevant team to look into it

Comment: I've check that there's a major updates on foursquare Web UI, is the api also affected by these changes?